# Rename Navigation Properties while keeping data intact in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Have an **Order** table with several **foreign keys** to a **User** table (different types of users).

The **Order** entity has multiple properties that represent the keys over to the User table.

The problem is these navigation properties get named User1, User2, User3 etc...

Is there a way to update the names of these properties and keep them intact when updating the datamodel?

For example, some times during development, if I make a change to this table, I will some times delete the table from the model, update and rebuild etc.

I think I will just have to manually rename these properties and remember to do this if I update the table and datamodel, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **[db-migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)** feature helps you to do that. advantage is that it helps you to have an archive of changes you have made during development. for each change you have a class that represent changes happened to database.

after enabling the migration for your project :

first turn off automatic update

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
```

then use the **[code-first migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)** to generate migration class. write this in  package manager :

```
add-migration renameColumns
```

then edit the created class to replace add/drop with rename.

```
   public override void Up()
    {
        RenameColumn("Orders", "OldColumn", "NewColumn");
```

finally run update command in package manager to effect database

```
  Update-Database
```